# How to remove Visual Studio 'IDE' warnings for a Unity project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, warnings

I've been trying to get rid off `IDE` warnings for a Unity project:

[image]

While `csc.rsp` works for `CS` warnings, it doesn't for `IDE` warnings:

`-nowarn:CS0649,IDE0063,IDE0071`

**Question:**

How to remove IDE warnings for a Unity project?

Comment: Unity will ocasionally regenerate the csproj, so your only choice is to make a post asset generation script and modify the csproj. Since this is time consuming and quite complicated, the best solution imho is to do what you did. Turn off warnnings in errorlist inside VS , and only fix warnings whenever the Unity console warns you.
Ps: Will not write a complete answer since as i said it is time consuming to write one..., but ehre you go: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetPostprocessor.html ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the simplest and most straightforward approach:

**(for suppressing warnings solution-wide)**

- no need to use `CodeAnalysisRuleSet`
- no need to use `AssetPostprocessor` nor `ProjectFilesGenerator`

  - both being error-prone and unfriendly as one can be

Instead,

**.editorconfig**

Visual Studio 2019 is smart enough to pick it up and apply it to all projects:

```
[*.{cs,vb}]

# IDE0051 Private member is unused.
dotnet_diagnostic.IDE0051.severity = none
```

If you need more granularity, add specific `.editorconfig` files at projects that needs different rules.

Of course you lose the GUI editing aspect but it isn't really a stopper in my case.

Comment: Nice solution, stealing this

Comment: I am glad that your problem has been solved, you can mark it as answer as it would be helpful to anyone who encounters similar issues.

Comment: I still need to wait 23 hours actually !

Answer (score 0):

You can mark these Unity functions as used by the engine by `Regenerate project file` in Unity Preferences:

`Edit Preferences` => `External Tools` => `Regenerate project files`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but I recently spent quite a while trying to fix a similar problem and couldn't use the accepted solution, so I wanted to share mine.

Opening scripts from imported Unity assets in Visual Studio triggers code analysis on these and displays warnings/suggestions, cluttering the error list with stuff you are not gonna fix, cause it's not yours. It's gonna get replaced if you update/re-download the asset and it's not gonna be in your Git. You can't just change project settings manually cause they will get overridden by auto-generated Unity project files. For some reason, I was not even able to open project settings from Visual Studio's context menus.

I couldn't find an .editorconfig solution to change the Warning Level globally (and override it in my projects), instead of changing specific warnings severity.

The solution is to use a custom AssetPostprocessor's OnGeneratedCSProject method to modify Unity generated project files. You need to create a class in, for example, "Assets/Project/Editor/Scripts". The important parts in that path are "Assets" (obviously) and "Editor" (so your class is included in Editor only files), you can change the other parts to what you like. I like to place all of my files in "Assets/Project", so they don't mix with files from imported Assets. I place all my scripts in either "Assets/Project/Scripts" or "Assets/Project/Editor/Scripts".

Now, here is the code for that class:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using UnityEditor;

namespace WhatEverNameSpaceYouAreUsingEventuallyEndingWith.Editor {

    public class CsprojPostProcessor : AssetPostprocessor {

        private const string PATTERN = "<WarningLevel>\\d+</WarningLevel>";
        private const string REPLACEMENT = "<WarningLevel>0</WarningLevel>";

        private static readonly string[] MyProjectFiles = { "Assembly-CSharp.csproj", "Assembly-CSharp-Editor.csproj" };

        private static bool IsOneOfMyProjects(string projectFilePath) {
            projectFilePath = projectFilePath.Replace('\\', '/');

            foreach(string projectFile in MyProjectFiles) {
                if(projectFilePath.EndsWith('/' + projectFile)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        private static string OnGeneratedCSProject(string path, string content) {
            return !IsOneOfMyProjects(path) ? Regex.Replace(content, PATTERN, REPLACEMENT) : content;
        }

    }

}
```

Once your AssetPostprocessor is ready, go back to Unity, go to "Edit" > "Preferences..." > "External Tools" and click the "Regenerate project files" button to update your csproj files.
Visual Studio should stop showing you warnings/suggestions for files that are not part of your own projects. (Unity 2022.3.21f1, Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) Version 17.9.2)